# Criar uma pesquisa dentro de um select

Tags: php, mysql, select, algoritmo-de-busca

queria saber algum método para incorporar uma busca para, facilitar o uso do select num sistema com muitas categorias, olhando pela internet,achei um script pago que possui uma solução, digamos que melhor. irei deixar logo abaixo uma imagem que mostra bem isso.

Se precisar do código do meu select, basta pedir, preciso urgentemente do código. Um abraço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) é uma solução gratuita, e o resultado é exatamente o da sua imagem. Parece que a tal solução paga usa o Select2...

Comment: bfavaretto Você é um gênio, como foi difícil resolver isso. Me obriguei a pedir ajuda, vendo isso, farei mais vezes. Foi simples e perfeito. Obrigado também ao Anderson, vou estudar sua maneira também, conhecimento nunca é o bastante! Um abraço. \m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com o [bootstrap](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/), você tem a propriedade chamada `data-live-search="true"` que permite fazer pesquisas no select